# PyQt5 - resize label to fill the whole window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, window, label

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.label.resize(800, 600)
        self.label.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.label.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source is self.label and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
            self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(
                self.label.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is my application, my goal is simple - have an image that fills the whole window and resizes after the window resize.

This code works okay in resizing the image, but the label doesn't cover the whole window, I have those "borders". How can I remove them/resize the label to window size? 
I am working on Windows if this changes things.

[image: Window look]

That is the effect I get now.

Comment: What is desired behavior of the application? When the picture `image.jpg` does **not** fit into to the window (like in the given screen-shot), what should happen? The picture's aspect ratio should change? Or part of the picture should be cropped?

Comment: @Matho Picture should be covering the whole window, if it is too small it should be scaling up. Right now if I resize the picture scales, but I don't want those grey "borders".

Comment: aspect ratio of the image (and window widget) should be preserved or it have to follow the aspect ratio of the window?

Comment: I think it should be more or less preserved, but I'll take the second option also :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it in PyQt4, so I'm not 100% sure if it will work for PyQt5, but I guess it should (some minor modifications might be needed, e.g. import PyQt5 instead of PyQt4).

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(800, 600)
        pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")
        self.pixmap = pixmap1.scaled(self.width(), self.height())
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(1, 1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")
        self.pixmap = pixmap1.scaled(self.width(), self.height())
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.resize(self.width(), self.height())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The most important for you is definition of `resizeEvent`. You could use already defined `self.pixmap` and just resize it, but the quality of the image would degrade the more resizing you use. Therefore, it's better always create new `pixmap` scaled to current `width` and `height` of the `Window`.

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a `QLabel` inside the separate `QWidget`. You can simply inherit `QLabel` instead of `QWidget`. It will make your code more simple and cleaner:

```
class MyLabelPixmap(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source is self and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
            self.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(self.size()))
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

In case you would like to embed your `MyLabelPixmap` widget  into the `QMainWindow` just add in your `QMainWindow.__init__`

```
self.myLabelPixmap = MyLabelPixmap()
self.setCentralWidget(self.myLabelPixmap)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I accepted the other one because it was first, but thanks nevertheless!