# PYQT5: Prevent image label changing window size

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm creating a simple image viewer with the ability to cycle through a list of images with left/right arrow keys. the problem is that when bigger images come in the sequence, the window size also grows bigger. I want the image to turn smaller to accommodate the window size, not the other way around. Also, I want to make it so that the image will change its size (though never bigger than its original size) when the user resizes the window.  How would I go about doing these?

```py
import sys
import os
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image_label = qtw.QLabel(alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_handler()
        self.curr_img = self.images[0]
        self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap(os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images', self.curr_img))
        self.resize_image(0)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)
        self.viewer()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewer_widget)
        self.setStyleSheet("""* {
            background-color: #0d0d0d;
        }
        .QLabel {
            border-style: none;
        }
        .QMainWindow {
            border-style: none;
        }
        """)
        self.show()

    def image_handler(self):
        self.images = [image for image in os.listdir(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images')]

    def resize_image(self, mode=0):
        if mode == 0:
            img_width = self.curr_img_pixmap.width()
            img_height = self.curr_img_pixmap.height()
            if img_width > self.width():
                self.curr_img_pixmap = self.curr_img_pixmap.scaledToWidth(self.width())
            elif img_height > self.height():
                self.curr_img_pixmap = self.curr_img_pixmap.scaledToHeight(self.height())
            else:
                self.curr_img_pixmap = self.curr_img_pixmap.scaledToHeight(self.height())

    def viewer(self):
        self.viewer_widget = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.viewer_widget.setCentralWidget(self.image_label)

    def change_image(self, direction):
        current_index = self.images.index(self.curr_img)
        if direction == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            if current_index == 0:
                return
            self.curr_img = self.images[current_index-1]
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap(os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images', self.curr_img))
            self.resize_image(0)
            self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)
        if direction == qtc.Qt.Key_Right:
            print(current_index)
            if current_index == len(self.images)-1:
                return
            self.curr_img = self.images[current_index+1]
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap(os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images', self.curr_img))
            self.resize_image(0)
            self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            self.change_image(qtc.Qt.Key_Left)
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Right:
            self.change_image(qtc.Qt.Key_Right)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.resize_image(0)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*P.S: The code [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html) is not in python.*

Comment: See my answer to a related post: [Resizing a window with PyQT5 - how do I reduce the size of a widget to allow the window to be shrunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67952671/2001654) (not the solution provided by the OP). The concept is that QLabel doesn't allow to be resized to a size smaller than the pixmap set for it (only larger sizes are possible), so the simplest solution is to use a custom widget.

Comment: @musicamante I can't comment on your other post so I'm asking this here: You say it's a bad idea to use QScrollArea for this but if I wanted to provide a zoom in/out function for the image then wouldn't the QScrollArea be ideal? Or is there another way to do so?

Comment: *IF* you also need a zoom feature, then things are obviously very different and a QScrollArea obviously *could* make sense, but then other question rise: what should happen if the window is resized? Should it keep the current ratio between image scale and window size? Or should it try to adapt the "current scale" to the new size? And should the scale adapt according to the minimum dimension (width or height) or the maximum?

Answer (score 0):

use .scaled method with keepAspectRatio and width and height of QLabel

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image_label = qtw.QLabel(alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.image_handler()
        self.curr_img = self.images[0]
        self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap(os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images', self.curr_img))
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap.scaled(self.image_label.width(), self.image_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.viewer()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewer_widget)
        self.setStyleSheet("""* {
            background-color: #0d0d0d;
        }
        .QLabel {
            border-style: none;
        }
        .QMainWindow {
            border-style: none;
        }
        """)
        self.show()

    def image_handler(self):
        self.images = [image for image in os.listdir(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images')]

    def viewer(self):
        self.viewer_widget = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.viewer_widget.setCentralWidget(self.image_label)

    def change_image(self, direction):
        current_index = self.images.index(self.curr_img)
        if direction == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            if current_index == 0:
                return
            self.curr_img = self.images[current_index-1]
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap(os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images', self.curr_img))
            self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap.scaled(self.image_label.width(), self.image_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        if direction == qtc.Qt.Key_Right:
            if current_index == len(self.images)-1:
                return
            self.curr_img = self.images[current_index+1]
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap(os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Python\images', self.curr_img))
            self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap.scaled(self.image_label.width(), self.image_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.SmoothTransformation))

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            self.change_image(qtc.Qt.Key_Left)
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Right:
            self.change_image(qtc.Qt.Key_Right)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        #self.resize_image(0)
        print(event)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap.scaled(self.image_label.width(), self.image_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.SmoothTransformation))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This unfortunately has the issue that once an image is set, it's still not possible to resize the main window to a size smaller than what's been defined.

Comment: There is also another issue: resizing doesn't take into account the actual widget used for the pixmap (`self.image_label`), but the size of the window. This can become very problematic, since a QMainWindow can have other widgets in it (menu bar, status bar, dock widgets and tool bars) and the result is that this will most certainly cause recursion.

Comment: self.image_label.setMinimumSize(1, 1)  solves resize window to smaller size

Comment: for width and height i changed it to take Qlabel width and height as suggested

Comment: that's better, but still doesn't completely consider the optional widgets of the main window: if a dock widget or tool bar is shown/hidden/resized the main window won't receive a resize event, with the result that the image won't be resized accordingly. That's one of the main reasons for which handing of such events should be done on the widget that is being resized (by implementing the subclass or at least by using an event filter), and not on the parent alone.